# select tableschema and tablename from a json variable and copy data from these tables of Azure SQL to Blob Storage

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to create a variable that contain json like this:

```
{
    "tables": [{
            "tableschema":"temp1",
            "tablename":"prova1",
            "datecolumn":"data",
            "histdate":"2021-01-01"
        },{
            "tableschema":"temp2",
            "tablename":"prova2",
            "datecolumn":"data",
            "histdate":"2021-01-01"
        }]
}
```

and then I have to select tables of this json and copy data from these tables of Azure SQL to Blob Storage.
I have tried in this way, but it is wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you already have tables list as a JSON in the parameter, there is no need to use another variable for it. Change the parameter type as `Object` and use this parameter directly in the Foreach expression.

[image]

Here, my table names are `temp1`, `temp2` and schema is `dbo` which is same for both.

`@pipeline().parameters.Table['tables']`

[image]

Sequential is used to execute the activities inside Foreach sequentially. If you uncheck it, the copy data activity for every iteration inside it will be executed parallelly. It's up to you to decide upon it.

Inside ForEach, take the copy activity and use SQL table, Blob dataset as source and sink of the copy activity respectively.

In the SQL table dataset, create two dataset parameters `schemaname`, `tablename` of string type.

[image]

Click on Edit and use the above parameters in the table like below.

[image]

Now, give the `@item().tableschema` and `@item().tablename` to the parameters in the copy activity source.

[image]

For the sink, here for sample I took csv file. you can use your dataset. Create a string parameter `filename` like above and give that in the Blob file path like below.

[image]

Give the below expression in the sink of the copy activity.

`@concat(item().tablename,'.csv')`

This expression will create `<tablename>.csv` file.

As I am copying to csv files, I have given `.csv` in the concat function. You need to give the extension as per your requirement.

[image]

Now, execute the pipeline and your tables will be copied to Blob files like mine.

[image]